# Libreoffice help fails to open

Tags: upgrade, libreoffice

File not found

Firefox can’t find the file at /usr/share/libreoffice/help/index.html?Target=swriter/.uno:HelpIndex&Language=en-US&System=UNIX&Version=7.3.

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04. Somewhere during the upgrade I remember seeing a message about installing Libreoffice as a snap.  When I tried to do this it said it was already installed so I left it alone.  It did upgrade to 7.3 as you can see above. I tried to install the help files but got a message that they are already installed.  Not sure what to do now, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: This is probably related to Firefox (being a snap) and not to LO. It is a bug that should be fixed.

Comment: Agreed with @FedKad. There should be some way to edit the snap sandbox or something. Here's a workaround. In a terminal, run: `mkdir -p ~/Downloads && rsync -Pav /usr/share/libreoffice/help ~/Downloads/libreoffice-help && firefox ~/Downloads/libreoffice-help/help/en-US/text/shared/05/new_help.html`. You can re-run this as necessary.

Comment: The workaround by Adam Monsen was successful for me.  I'm happy for now.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and seem not to have it anymore - maybe you can tell me why.

My Ubuntu Studio 22.04 lts was a clean install to my existing drive from a downloaded ISO and then I copied some of my USER files from backup. After using APT to install LO Help I searched the problem which may be due to SNAP.

Some of the backup I had copied was a firefox folder from when I had removed the distribution version and downloaded FF to my user space to unpack and use. That version of FF had no problem with displaying LO Help but LO still didn't.  Then I put a symbolic link "firefox" for the user space version in /usr/bin.  LO used that instead of the snap version and found LO Help. Then I removed the symbolic link "firefox" from  /usr/bin.  LO now accesses LO Help with the snap version of FF.

Here are some version details:

file:///usr/share/libreoffice/help/en-US/text/swriter/main0000.html?System=UNIX&DbPAR=WRITER&HID=SW_HID_EDIT_WIN#bm_id3147244

108.0.2 (64-bit)
Mozilla Firefox Snap for Ubuntu
canonical-002-1.0

user firefox (updated when opened maybe before accessing LO Help):
108.0.2 (64-bit)

file:///H:/usr/share/libreoffice/help/en-US/text/swriter/main0000.html

Ubuntu Studio 22.04
KDE Plasma V: 5.24.4
KDE Frameworks V: 5.92.0
Qt V: 5.15.3
Kernel V: 5.15.0-57-lowlatency (64-bit)
Graphics Platform X11

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Your post is extremely difficult to understand.  If you are proposing a solution, then please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1451219/edit) your post to make that clear.  You say, *"maybe you can tell me why."* which sounds like a question.  Also, see the [formatting](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) guide (for how to format a list of instructions) and the [advanced formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help) guide (for how to format input/output in code-blocks).  That will make your post more readable.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update to prior post:

This “fix” kept working through an update of snap-FF.  After installing Xubuntu linux in a reformatted partition and re-installing LO Help the problem was back but was not immediately fixed by the method described.  After installing Ubuntu Studio over Xubuntu (and apache2 and wine) I was surprised snap-FF began to find LO Help.

Instead of deleting the /usr/bin/ symbolic link to FF in my user space I had renamed it as Firefox.
Sometimes snap-FF runs when Firefox is used:  another thing some else may be able to explain!

Does making snap-FF available to LO by whatever means also make snap-FF run less securely?  When snap-FF can’t access LO Help from the supplied link it can open files further below in the folder structure such as:
file:///usr/share/libreoffice/help/en-US/text/swriter/main0000.html

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1282025)