# LibreOffice Help files exist but are not available

Tags: updates, libreoffice

When pressing F1 or clicking on help from any LibreOffice program, I get this error:
File not found

Firefox can’t find the file at /usr/share/libreoffice/help/index.html?Target=swriter/SW_HID_EDIT_WIN&Language=en-US&System=UNIX&Version=7.3.

```
Check the file name for capitalization or other typing errors.
Check to see if the file was moved, renamed or deleted.
```

The files at the /usr/share/libreoffice/help location. How can I get them to work.
I've updated 3 computers with Ubuntu 22.04 and they 2 have this problem. One computer was installed from usb, the other 2 were updated by software updater. the one that works was updated with software updater.

The .html files won't load into a brower either.
any suggestions

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1424163/libreoffice-help-fails-to-open#comment2479504_1424163

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was Firefox, not displaying files from the system. When they are on the desktop, it is no problem. How to resolve? I do not know. I took the Gnome Web Browser as a default browser. This way it works fine.